# Getting list of table names from database in Android application

Tags: android, sqlite, tablename

I am trying to get a list of table names from an SQLite database. I manage to get this, but I also get temporary table names like 'android_metadata' and 'sqlite_sequence'. I want to exclude these 2.

However, I can't get it to work right.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = 
getBaseContext().openOrCreateDatabase("vocabularyDatabase", 
MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(  "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master 
      WHERE (type = 'table') AND (name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence' OR 
      name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata') ", 
      null);

    if (c.moveToFirst()){
        while (!c.isAfterLast() ){
                listOfWords.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) 
                 );
                c.moveToNext();

        }
    }
```

Comment: That is odd. Why don't you know the tables of the DB?

Comment: Well, I know the tables, but the idea is that the user of the app has made several lists stored as tables in a database, and should be able to see all the lists (tables), to be able to pick one of them. So this piece of code is just to test the code.

Comment: That is what I thought - you should never create tables while running a program. A DB schema should be fixed and only data be added - not tables.

Comment: How about `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE (NOT (name = 'android_metadata' OR name LIKE '%sqlite_sequence%')) AND type = 'table'`

Comment: To Mike T: Didn´t work unfortunately. To juergen d: Why not let the user make a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the current row is for `android_metadata`. The expression `name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata'` will be false, but the expression `name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence'` will be true. So the WHERE clause reduces to `true AND (true OR false)`, which is true.

You need to replace the `OR` with `AND`:

```
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND (name NOT LIKE 'sqlite_sequence' AND
       name NOT LIKE 'android_metadata')
```

If you really want to use `OR`, you have to apply [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and negate the entire condition:

```
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND NOT (name LIKE 'sqlite_sequence' OR
           name LIKE 'android_metadata')
```

Alternatively, simply use IN with a list:

```
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND name NOT IN ('sqlite_sequence', 'android_metadata')
```